# how to repair ATX PSU 5VSB problem

Tags: power-supply, atx

The 5VSB rail puts out voltages that are way out of the nomial range.
It sweeps from 2.5 to 7.3 V or better said, jumps values randomly.
All other rails are ok. The PSU turns on fine, but sometimes the PC doesn't boot. Just the fans and lights turn on. The graphics card is not powered from the PSU directly, so there is also no signal to display when that happens.
I replaced the PSU with a new one and the PC works fine now, so the 5VSB rail has to be the problem.
I opened it up and there is no sign of fried components or bulges on electrolytic caps. What should i do next to determine why the 5VSB output is not within tolerance?

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that the +5SB is universally a separate power supply. 
It is simple, but still sourced from the AC mains rectified, so as with all power supplies of this type it will bite you hard if touched.

Here is a website with an introduction to a [basic PC power supply](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/anatomy-of-switching-power-supplies/2/), with a schematic. Your may vary but it will give you some ideas.

If your power supply is good once powered up then most likely the fault is only in the SB power supply.

1. Trace back your +5SB to find the regulator (almost always a linear regulator)
2. Find the unregulated supply for the regulator to see if it is varying or just the regulator output.

There are not many components, but do be careful, the high voltage side can kill you.